# large file upload with php

Tags: php, file-upload

My upload was working file till i finished my work last night, but today when i try to upload a file size > 2MB,  i am getting the exception `"The file is too large (Server Exception)."` can any one kindly tell me why is this problem comming, as 2MB is not a big size that php can't handle. My upload script is :

```
function uploadFile(){

        if ( $this->error == 0 ){

            if ( $this->destination == null ){

                if ( $this->ext !== null || $this->ext !== '' ){

                    if ( in_array( $this->ext , $this->allowedExtensions ) ){

                        $tmp_file = $this->tmp_name;

                        if ( file_exists( $tmp_file ) ) {

                                             $this->fileUid = md5(time());
                                             move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_name, "/home/totalrec/upload/" . $this->fileUid.'.'.$this->ext);


                            return true;

                        } else {

                            $this->error = $tmp_file;

                        }

                    } else {

                        $this->error = 10;

                    }

                } else {

                    $this->error = 9;

                }

            } else {

            }

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `php.ini` for the entries `upload_max_filesize` (that defaults to 2MB), `post_max_size` and `memory_limit`.

They all must be bigger than the file you are trying to upload.

Comment: i can see upload_max_filesize which is 128 MB (php configuration file) but can't find the post_max_size on cPanel. where can i find php.ini file?

Comment: If you cannot find those entries then create them. But if you are limited to cPanel I'm afraid you may not be able to change any configuration you want.